# How do I search open editors for a file with a given extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode extension and I need to search the open editors for a `.src` file.  Not the workspace.  I can do `vscode.workspace.findFiles()` but I need something similar for the `vscode.window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no API to list the open editors. There is however a pretty highly upvoted feature request for it - if this API is added, you could simply loop over the open editors and check the file paths for the extension.

[API Access to "Open Editors" (#15178)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15178)

Note that there is a possible workaround [suggested in one of the comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15178#issuecomment-283072868). The `workbench.action.nextEditor` command can be combined with the `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` API to loop over all open files and create a list along the way. However, this seems rather hacky.

Comment: This API feature request was integrated as part of the April 2022 release of vscode. There doesn't seem to be any extension yet though...